# Invalid displayName passed to MCPeerID

Tags: ios, ipad, multipeer-connectivity, mpc

When I tried to pass device udid + device name, i received below crash

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid displayName passed to MCPeerID'

Comment: where is the code??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
init(displayName myDisplayName: String)
```

From [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/multipeerconnectivity/mcpeerid/1407089-init):

> The maximum allowable length is **63 bytes** in UTF-8 encoding.
>
> The displayName parameter may not be **nil** or an **empty string**.
>
> This method throws an exception if the **displayName** value is **too long**,
>   empty, or nil.

In your case, you are passing `udid + device name` which is exceeding the limit allowed i.e. **63 bytes (63 characters)**

and will throw an exception saying:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid displayName passed to
>   MCPeerID

Just to **Debug:**

print `lengthOfBytes` for your `udid + device name` before passing it in `init(displayName myDisplayName: String)` it would definitely exceeds the limit allowed.

```
print((UIDevice.current.name+udid).lengthOfBytes(using: String.Encoding.utf8))
```